# React-native set colour to radio button's label

Tags: react-native, radio-group

I am using[react-native-radio-buttons-group](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-radio-buttons-group) for radio buttons in my app. I have a bit of difficulty to paint the labels of the radio buttons in some colors. I tried the example:

```
 {
    label: 'option one',
    color: '#FFFFFF',
 },
```

but only the bullets were painted. I want to paint the labels as well.

Now I got this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my problem. It is a bit hacky but works. I wrapped the labels in `<Text>` tags whit inline style as follows:

```
deliveryRadioData: [
    {
      id: 1,
      label: (
        <Text style={{color: '#FFFFFF'}}>{'option one'}</Text>
      ),
      selected: true,
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      size: 16,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      label: (
        <Text style={{color: '#FFFFFF'}}>
          {'option two'}
        </Text>
      ),
      selected: false,
      color: '#FFFFFF',
      size: 16,
    },
  ],
};
```

Now the radio buttons look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is `labelStyle` prop.

Otherwise, try [react-native-btr](https://github.com/ThakurBallary/react-native-btr)

> NOTE: This package is updated and actively maintained in
>   react-native-btr library. Hence, we recommend you to use this
>   component from react-native-btr library.

Comment: Hi Tan Dat, there is no such property.

Comment: That library that you suggest has more items that I need.

Answer (score 0):

The labelStyle you want is added to the RadioGroup.

```js
      <RadioGroup
        radioButtons={radioButtons}
        onPress={handleOnPress}
        selectedId={value}
        containerStyle={styles.radioGroup}
        labelStyle={styles.labelStyle}
        layout='row'
      />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).